# How reliable are Covid-19 antigen quick tests for vaccinated, asymptomatic infected?

Tags: covid-19, test

A few weeks back, virologist [Dr. Drosten tweeted](https://twitter.com/c_drosten/status/1461975726933032965) "Before onset of symptoms, quick tests are not sensitive enough [...] **Sensitivity appears lower in vaccinated (preliminary data)** [...]" (emphasis mine)

Can we put numbers on the bolded part - how much lower is sensitivity in vaccinated? Is this the same for all antigen tests or dependent on type (do we even know)?

Comment: Given that his statement is based on preliminary data I think it's a good bet we don't know.

Comment: Maybe. OTOH the statement is weeks old and there may be preprints or so in open now

Comment: Purely circumstantially, my wife and I were vaccinated with J&J, she got covid and tested negative on the day she most probably infected me, 4 days after she was infected